# Azure queue trigger function created with serverless doesn't fire

Tags: azure, triggers, azure-functions, serverless, azure-queues

Creating a **queue trigger** function using **serverless** creates the function, but when a new message is added to the queue it doesn't trigger. A queue trigger function created from the **portal** using the same configuration (queue name, connection string) gets triggered when a new message is added to the queue.

serverless.yml

```
...    
functions:
  storageQueue:
    handler: src/handlers/goodbye.sayGoodbye
    events:
      - queue: example-queue
        name: myQueueItem
        connection: STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING
```

This is the json file generated for the queue trigger function from **serverless**.
function.json

```
{
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "myQueueItem",
      "queueName": "example-queue",
      "connection": "STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING"
    }
  ],
  "entryPoint": "sayGoodbye",
  "scriptFile": "../src/handlers/goodbye.js"
}
```

This is the json file generated for the function if its created from the **portal**. function.json

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myQueueItem",
      "queueName": "example-queue",
      "connection": "STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING",
      "direction": "in",
      "type": "queueTrigger"
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see the bindings part is the same for both functions, but only the one created from the portal works.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the workaround I did to create an Azure Serverless Function of JavaScript Stack - Azure Queue Storage Trigger in Visual Studio Code and it is triggering successfully after adding a message to the created Queue.**

And the code is:
**function.json**

```
{
"bindings": [
{
"name": "myQueueItem",
"type": "queueTrigger",
"direction": "in",
"queueName": "js-queue-items",
"connection": "storageaccountjbd99_STORAGE"
}
]
}
```

**host.json**

```
{
"version": "2.0",
"logging": {
"applicationInsights": {
"samplingSettings": {
"isEnabled": true,
"excludedTypes": "Request"
}
}
},
"extensionBundle": {
"id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
"version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
}
}
```

**local.settings.json**

```
{ 
"IsEncrypted": false,
"Values": {
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "Azure Connection Storage string",
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
"storageaccountjbd99_STORAGE": "Azure Connection Storage string"
}
}
```

[image]
Here the `AzureWebJobsStorage` and `storageaccountjbd99_STORAGE` connection string values should be same if you're connecting to Azure Storage Account.

- If the storage account is created in Azure, while creating the function it asks to select the Azure Storage account or use local storage account, here I selected the existing Azure Storage account so the connection value is the storage account name.
- After that, I run the function and in Azure Storage Explorer, create the queue name called `js-queue-items` and added the message in the Queue.

**After adding the message, the function triggered its functionality and shown the output as you see in below:**

[image]